# ES6 Fat arrow in react this.setState ESLint error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a small code in react

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  return { userAnnotations: [...prevState.userAnnotations, selText] };
});
```

How can i convert this into single line as ES Lint is giving error `[eslint] Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; parenthesize the returned value and move it immediately after the`=>`. (arrow-body-style)`

I tried to remove curly braces around return but then there is some another error occurs.

Please help.

Comment: `this.setState(prevState => ({ userAnnotations: [...prevState.userAnnotations, selText] }));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is get rid off `return`

```
    this.setState(prevState => ({ userAnnotations: 
          [...prevState.userAnnotations, selText]
    }))
```

Comment: this.setState(prevState => ({
      userAnnotations: [...prevState.userAnnotations, selText],
    }));

Comment: Need to remove outer parentheses too

Comment: @raju yes that was one of things other than `return`